# Access within iframes

Tags: javascript, firefox, linkify

I'm using a short snippet of linkify derived code to access all the text inodes within a webpage from a Firefox extension. This looks like this, so nothing particularly interesting:

```
var notInTags=[
    'a', 'head', 'noscript', 'option', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'textarea'
    ];

    var xpath = ".//text()[not(ancestor::"+notInTags.join(') and not(ancestor::')+")]";

    var candidates = window.content.document.evaluate(xpath, window.content.document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to grab the text nodes from any iframes present as well please?
Specifically, is using

```
iframe.window.content.document
```

likely to get me anywhere (Doesn't seem to), or am I am I barking up the wrong tree?

Cheers :)

**Edit 2: This is the complete updated function (again)**

```
    rsfindmod.searchiframes= function(candidates){
//This fixes cases where a redirecting page uses frames (Primarily search engines etc)
    const urlRegex = /\b(https?:\/\/[^\s+\"\<\>]+)/ig;
    var framesets = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('frame','iframe','frameset');

    for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
    if (urlRegex.test(framesets[i])) {
    alert('test');
    var document2 = framesets[i].contentDocument;
    var notInTags=[
    'a', 'head', 'noscript', 'option', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'textarea'
    ];

    var xpath = ".//text()[not(ancestor::"+notInTags.join(') and not(ancestor::')+")]";

    var textnodes = document2.evaluate(xpath, document2, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for(var i = 0; i < textnodes.length; i++) {
        candidates.push(textnodes[i]);
    }
}   
}
}
```

**Edit 3: A slightly better function?**

```
rsfindmod.searchiframes= function(candidates, frame, documentList){
//This fixes cases where a redirecting page uses frames (Primarily search engines etc)
    const framesets = frame.frames;

    for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
    var document2 = framesets[i].contentWindow.document;
    var notInTags=[
    'a', 'head', 'noscript', 'option', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'textarea'
    ];
    alert('test');
    var xpath = ".//text()[not(ancestor::"+notInTags.join(') and not(ancestor::')+")]";

    var textnodes = document2.evaluate(xpath, document2, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for(var i = 0; i < textnodes.length; i++) {
        candidates.push(textnodes[i]);
        alert('test1'); 
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `iframe.contentDocument` (or `iframe.contentWindow.document`, but the former is simpler).

Comment: Doesn't like that at all. Please see the first post for the complete function.

Comment: Doesn't even get as far as the test alert. In theory, this ought to be finding all the iframes/ framesets on the page, adding them to the array 'framesets', and then pushing all the text nodes to the candidates array.

Comment: Updated what I've got again to add a URL test before I try accessing the contentDocument. This still doesn't work, but neither does it make Firefox throw a complete wobbly!

Comment: Are your subframes from a different origin (e.g an ad server)?  If they are, then you can't get at their contents, of course.

Comment: Ah, that would be why then :( I'm trying to fix a page redirected through a file search engine. The original page is displayed in an iframe witihin a page on the search engine's server. Any easy way around that? I'm thinking I could possibly do something with a grabber, and then process this as an ordinary document somehow?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not interested in altering the contents of the page, only grabbing the text nodes :)

Comment: Hmm.  From inside an extension (which I just realized is what you're talking about), you should be able to do .contentDocument on anything.  What exception were you getting when you did that originally?

Comment: No errors as such, it just hangs Firefox with 25% CPU usage until it decides the script is broke.

Comment: Adding the URL regex test fixes the hang (A frameset tag doesn't necessarily have to contain a URL, hence trying to find nodes in something that isn't DOM is going to die?), but that is just dumping everything out as not matching it.

Comment: I've been meddling with the function :0 Edit 3 picks up the frames correctly (I think), but then complains that document2 is undefined.

Comment: In your edit 3, `framesets` is a list of Window objects, not of elements (and I'd just call that list `childWindows` or something).  So you just want to set `document2 = framesets[i].document`.